# Past vs. perfect in present-tense narrative

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, present-tense

When telling a story using the present tense, should events at a specific time in the past be recounted in the past perfect or in the past tense?

For example: I know to write

> Jack entered the room and sat down. The fight had drained him, and he needed to rest.

, but is

> Jack enters the room and sits down. The fight drained him, and he needs to rest.

or

> Jack enters the room and sits down. The fight had drained him, and he needs to rest.

correct, and why?

(To me, the latter seems obviously correct, but someone recently insisted to be that the former is correct, and I could not defend or explain my position, so I'm asking here.)

Please note that I'm asking according to traditional (prescriptive) grammar.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is suitable for migration to ELL. 


Comment: @Kris, I don't know -- nothing in the post to indicate that O.P. is ESL person, which seems more like what ELL is for (to me at least... obviously I'm still kind of green to all this)

Comment: @Kris http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4249. Fwiw, English is my only first language, I've always lived in an anglophone country, and I'm educated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if we're using strictly present tense, then I would think that the latter one needs to be tweaked (but is the correct one):

> Jack enters the room and sits down. The fight **has** drained him, and he needs to rest.

If that was a typo on your part, oops. Otherwise, I'd say that present perfect falls under "present" tense, while past perfect would fall under "past." But more than that, my reasoning behind this is the following quote from a book written entirely in present tense:

> What else can he do? There are at least twelve of them. They have made
>   a point of blocking the only exit. **They have just announced** their
>   intentions. And presumably they are all carrying heat. Besides, this
>   kind of thing is going to happen to him about every ten seconds when
>   he's on the Raft.
>
> Stephenson, Neal (2003-08-26). Snow Crash (Bantam Spectra Book)
>   (Kindle Locations 5311-5313). Random House Publishing Group. Kindle
>   Edition.

Not much in the way of grammar explanation, but there it is. **But honestly, it's a matter of your own personal style.** Do what feels right for the narrative you're telling.